# Python - Sorting list

Tags: python

I have a lists like the below:

```
list1 = [['4.00', '7.00'], ['4.00', '4.00'], ['4.00', '1.00']]
list2 = [['4.00', '7.00'], ['1.00', '7.00'], ['6.00', '7.00']]
```

If x values are equal, I want to sort the elements in ascending order based on y values and if y values are equal, want to sort based on x values like below:

```
sorted list1 = [['4.00', '1.00'], ['4.00', '4.00'], ['4.00', '7.00']]
sorted list2 = [['1.00', '7.00'], ['4.00', '7.00'], ['6.00', '7.00']]
```

I tried to use `sorted()`. But code becomes complicated when i try to compare the values of x to find out if they are the same and then giving key to `sorted()` based on that. Can I do it in a better way?

Comment: Isn't the way you're comparing them the same way lists would normally be compared?

Comment: yeah. I want to know if there is a simpler way by specifying some condition to check if x or y in list are equal in the key given to sorted() function..

Comment: If you've reached the point of checking `y` values, and they're still equal, why would going back to `x` change anything? You're only testing `y` when `x` was equal, so going back to `x` is pointless.

Comment: @ShadowRanger.. I just mentioned 2 different conditions.. 1. If x values are  equal, sort y. 2. If y values are equal sort x.

Comment: ... but that's the way it already works. What are you trying to do that's different?

Comment: @buddingengineer: What is the point? If all the `x` are equal, then you'd be sorting on `y` anyway. If the `x`s aren't equal, you'll sort on them (and it doesn't matter if `y` is equal or not, it's not even looked at). You've basically defined a restricted subset of the rules for lexicographic sorting, leaving out what to do if neither `x` nor `y` is equal for the whole list (which lexicographic ordering handles).

Comment: Ok! The problem is with my understanding of sorted() function. Thanks for making it clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sorted` already does what you want. Comparing `list`s is done lexicographically: The elements are compared from left to right until an unequal element is found, at which point the result of the comparison is the comparison on that first unequal element. For example, with no `key` function at all, your lists sort as you expect:

```
>>> list1 = [['4.00', '7.00'], ['4.00', '4.00'], ['4.00', '1.00']]
>>> list2 = [['4.00', '7.00'], ['1.00', '7.00'], ['6.00', '7.00']]
>>> sorted(list1)
[['4.00', '1.00'], ['4.00', '4.00'], ['4.00', '7.00']]
>>> sorted(list2)
[['1.00', '7.00'], ['4.00', '7.00'], ['6.00', '7.00']]
```

In the `list1` case, it correctly compares the first values, determines they're the same, and sorts on the second value; in the `list2` case, the first values all differ, so the second value is never even checked.